# Different list item permissions for 2 groups

Tags: list, workflow, permissions

I am trying to set list item permissions different for two group of users : Members and Manager. As shown in the scenario below, solution works for grou "Members", but not for group "Managers". Is suing workflow my only way out as stated here
[List permissions for different groups](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12281/list-permissions-for-different-groups)? Will workflow prevent Members from downloading to Excel ?

---

AddOnlyItem (Custom permission level)
-Add Items
-View Items
-View Pages
-Browse Directories
-Open

List1
-Advanced settings : Item-level permission set to Read items that were created by the user and Create items and edit items that were created by the user
-Group1 permission set to AddOnlyItem
-Group2 set to Contribute

Members
-Can add new  items to List1
-Should view or download only items of List1 created by same user
-**Good** : List1 behaves as expected considering above settings

Managers
-Should be able to view, edit or download any or all items of List1
-**Bad** : Actually Managers do not have access to any item since they were all created by others (the Members).

---

Your suggestions wil be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not set up 2 groups, different levels of permissions and then control by document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want through audience targeting of List View Web Parts.

Your first step is correct - create a custom permission level to prevent editing or deleting by people in the "Members" group.

However, you do not want to set the Advanced Settings - Item Level Permissions on the list because it will apply to Managers as well, as you have found out.

As I explain in [this other answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/184735/8992), you could use Audience Targeting on the List View Web Parts to get the separation you want. For instance for the default LVWP for your document library, set its target audience to be the "Managers" group.

Then, add another LVWP for the *same document library to the same page*, set its target audience to be the "Members" group, then set up a view for that LVWP that filters by `Created by = [Me]`, and show no toolbar so they can't change the view. They should still be able to upload documents through the Ribbon, but they will only be able to see a view that filters on their items.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will definitely give it a try,first thing tomorrow morning. i am not comfortable with LVWP, but I will learn more about it.